# Grails async Event handler fails to retrieve domain instance from persistence

Tags: hibernate, grails, asynchronous, grails-orm

I'm trying to create and persist an instance of Foo in a transactional service, and then once `Foo` instance has been persisted, fire an event to kick off some async processing on it.

The problem I am having is that when I attempt to retrieve the `Foo` instance from persistence in the event handler, the instance is not found.

My service method that persists the `Foo` instance looks like this:

```
Foo makeFoo() {
  def foo = new Foo(...).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
  notify("FOO_CREATED_EVT", foo.id)
  return foo
}
```

My event handler, which exists in a separate transactional service, looks like this:

```
@Selector("FOO_CREATED_EVT")
void onFooCreated(Long fooId) {
  def foo = Foo.get(fooId) // also tried findById, with the same outcome
  assert foo != null // fails
}
```

I've stepped through the code on both sides with sql logging enabled and verified that the `Foo` instance successfully persisted in `makeFoo()`, yet when `onFooCreated()` attempts to retrieve it,  it always fails.  So far as I know, flushing in the save before firing the event should result in the `Foo` instance being immediately persisted, however if I add a delay into onFooCreated:

```
Thread.sleep(1000)
def foo = Foo.get(fooId)
assert foo != null // succeeds
```

Then the operation succeeds, so I can only assume that there's a race condition because flush is not actually synchronously persisting the instance.

My project is using Grails 3.2 with Hibernate 5 and PostgreSQL 9.6.

I'm obviously doing something wrong but the documentation on async events is pretty sparse and have hit a wall troubleshooting this scenario :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `flush()` may have executed but the transaction has not been committed or closed yet so the data is not visible to the other thread since transactions are isolated and the other thread will use a separate connection.

You would need to ensure the transaction has been committed before firing the event.

Comment: Thanks Graeme - that makes sense.  I'm sure this is behavior that inherited from Hibernate, but while we're on the subject, doesnt this behavior kind of defeat the purpose of flush()?